# Minecraft 1.7.2 server, can't join from remote and even local user

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a problem with Minecraft Server 1.7.2, I started it successfully, my port is forwarded on router, another player can join to my server, but there is error in the server log:

[22:05:03 INFO]: GameProfile{id='null', name='Player'} (/IP:65158) lost connection: Disconnected

And also I tried to join from the machine were server is working and there was the same error.

Could you please advise, what can be the reason for that?

Also, please clarify if there is option for enabling DEBUG level logs on the server.

Comment: Are you using `localhost` to connect locally?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use localhost and 127.0.0.1 without any result

Comment: Okay, is `online-mode` set to false?

Comment: Well, it was set to true, now I'm able to join to the server! Great , thanks, it was my mistake.

Comment: Be aware, that this is possibly because of the answer given here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/143248/49600

Comment: I am able to join the server but when I do I can't speak or do any commands and I'm stuck in blocks.Then after a while It automatically kicks me saying.'Internal Exception: Java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I am aware that this question has already been answered in the comments. I'm writing this so this question will be removed from the list of unanswered questions.***

It seem that you use a cracked Minecraft launcher which means that your account can not be verified on the Mojang servers. A way around this is to go to `server.properties` and change online mode to `false` this will allow you to connect to your server without the server verifying the legitimacy of your account

**Original answer by [Dillmo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52890/dillmo).**