# Why does my Minecraft say "Bad login"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to log into Minecraft it connects online and my skin is there in single player but when I try to go onto a server it says bad login (If I try to login on Minecraft.net it lets me)

Answer (score 2):

The Mojang Minecraft servers are down or having instability issues right now. It affects everyone.

For private servers owners can (temporary) set online-mode to false in the server properties file. That will then skip the check, but it will also open up for trouble: Hacked clients and users can login under other users names.

You can check status for Mojang servers [officially here](https://help.mojang.com/) and [unofficially here](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/).